# Is there away to do array push with mathjs matrix objects?

Tags: javascript, mathjs

Well, the title says it all. I am looking for a way to add rows or columns to an object created with

```
mm = math.matrix([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]);
// can we do something like 
mm.push([0,1]);
```

I refer to the [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html) library here.

Comment: what is return type of *math.matrix*?
or try like this 
mm = math.matrix(mm,[0,1]);

Comment: Is called "DenseMatrix".

Comment: try like this 

**mm = math.matrix(mm,[0,1]);** may be it will work

Comment: @yugi that was my first intuition, too. But it's not working... can't believe this doesn't work. Rather feel like I am missing the obvious.

Answer (score 2):

i also checked  their docs..they don't have direct push or any other  functionality to achieve this.we have try our self in different manner to achieve that functionality .

1) convert to array and pass to matrix again

2) or add ur own method for  matrix object

```
 math.push=function(e){
 // ur own code to implement the push  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `push` like function available. You can of course open a request for this in the [issues section](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/issues/) of the project.

The solution that comes closest is using the [`concat`](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/concat.html) function:

```
mm = math.matrix([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]);
mm = math.concat(mm, [[0,1]], 0);
// mm now contains: [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [0, 1]]
```

The last number in the `concat` function specifies the dimension where to add the new data.